# Not sure why React is returning an object instead of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs

Skip over to the bottom to see what the issue looks like!

```
onInputChange(e){
    this.setState({
        search : e.target.value
    });
}

onSearchSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Going to dispatch the action */
    this.props.addThing(this.state.search);
    // this.setState({ search : '' })
}

renderThing(thing, index){
    debugger;
    return <div key={index}>{thing}</div>
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input value={this.state.search} onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} />
            <button onClick={this.onSearchSubmit.bind(this)} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            <h1>things</h1>
            {this.props.things.map(this.renderThing)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Also, I have this line but every source I see online isn't giving me clear answers as to what this is. Some say it is not necessary, or they say that this is what tells React what data type a prop is. I want to store the state of `things` in an array... so when someone adds stuff, it will just create a new array with that newly added state.

```
ThingIndex.propTypes = {
    things: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

Here is my actions...

```
export const ADD_THING = 'ADD_THING';

export function addThing(thing){
    return {
        type: ADD_THING,
        payload: thing
    }
};
```

Lastly but not least, my reducers...

```
import { ADD_THING } from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_THING:
        console.log(action.payload)
            return [...state, 
                // thing: action.payload };
                Object.assign({}, action.payload)
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**This is where I am confused and lost.** 
When I run the app, I type "HEY" in the Search Bar hit Search, and the debugger pops up consoling `HEY` (from the reducer).

Then I type `thing` and it says:

```
> thing
< Object {0: "H", 1: "E", 2: "Y"}
```

I say okay, at least the props are receiving the state... **but** when I type

```
> this.props
< Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined(…)
```

and now I am just completely lost and don't understand React-Redux whatsoever.

Then when I continue exectuing script... it says

```
< Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys 
{0, 1, 2}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array
 instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React
 add-ons. Check the render method of `ThingIndex`.
```

You help will be much appreciated, I just don't know who to turn to! I watched so many YouTube videos, medium articles, idk...

Comment: what is your problem, you are saying you are confused, maybe its time to go and sleep and start from ground up tomorrow.. just relax

Comment: `Object.assign({}, 'thing')` returns an object. `Object {0: "t", 1: "h", 2: "i", 3: "n", 4: "g"}`

Comment: `this` is undefined in `renderThing`, its not binded

Comment: That's where I thought the issue was triggering in, the reducer. I tried doing Object.assign([], action.payload) and it surprisingly rendered on the screen, but that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @webdeb, are you saying that `props` are undefined in `renderThing()`? Where is the scope of props defined? I thought it was available to all components!

Comment: yes, this is why you are using `this.onInputChange.bind(this)`! What is the **bind** doing?

Comment: It is available to all components, but this is NOT bind automatically to all the methods you define in a class. You have to bind **this** your self.. try with `this.renderThing.bind(this)`

Comment: @webdev Oh thank you so much. I thought I was bind was just "one of those things" you do to pass events. So do you think it is good practice to leave my code with  `Object.assign([], action.payload)`? It is rendering to the screen properly.
From my understanding, this line is creating a new ARRAY of the current state (Object) with the newly added state (action.payload).

Comment: "So do you think it is good practice to leave my code with Object.assign([], action.payload)" --- do you understand what that code does? If not - it's definitely not a good practice.